# Terraform AWS gitlab pipeline plan not recognizing changes

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, gitlab, gitlab-ci, terraform-provider-aws

I have few Terraform pipelines running on gitlab and this 1 pipeline that I am trying to setup for AWS does not want to work. Even though I am setting up the access key and secret as an environment variable it still does not run successfully `terraform init` unless I pass the access key and secret as backend-config like this: `terraform init -backend-config="access_key=$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_PIPELINE_TEST" -backend-config="secret_key=$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_PIPELINE_SECRET" -backend-config="region=$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION"`

Even more confusing is when I run just `terraform plan` it does not detect change but when I pass the var-file it works just fine. I am not sure what is the issue here. If anyone has faced this issue then please suggest what could I be doing wrong. Below is my gitlab CI file

```
image:
  name: hashicorp/terraform:latest
  entrypoint:
    - '/usr/bin/env'
    - 'PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin'

variables:
  hcm_dev_PLAN: hcm_dev_plan.tfplan
  hcm_shared_PLAN: hcm_shared_plan.tfplan
  hcm_prod_PLAN: hcm_prod_plan.tfplan

stages:
  - test
  - validate
  - plan
  - apply


.validate: &ValidateAnchor
  script:
    - |
      echo "I am inside the validate anchor step"
      if [[ ${CI_JOB_NAME} == "validate" ]]; then
        export access_key=${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_PIPELINE_TEST}
        export secret_key=${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_PIPELINE_SECRET}
        export region=${AWS_DEFAULT_REGION}
        terraform init -backend-config="access_key=$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_PIPELINE_TEST" -backend-config="secret_key=$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_PIPELINE_SECRET" -backend-config="region=$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION"
        echo "DEV successfully initialized!"
        terraform fmt
        terraform validate
      fi

.plan: &PlanAnchor
  script:
    - |
      if [[ ${CI_JOB_NAME} == "plan" ]]; then
        export access_key=${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_PIPELINE_TEST}
        export secret_key=${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_PIPELINE_SECRET}
        export region=${AWS_DEFAULT_REGION}
        terraform init -backend-config="access_key=$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_PIPELINE_TEST" -backend-config="secret_key=$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_PIPELINE_SECRET" -backend-config="region=$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION"
        echo "DEV successfully initialized!"
        terraform plan -out=$hcm_dev_PLAN
      fi


validate:
  <<: *ValidateAnchor
  stage: validate
  only:
    changes:
      - *

plan:
  <<: *PlanAnchor
  stage: plan
  only:
    changes:
      - *
  artifacts:
    name: plan
    paths:
      - "$CI_PROJECT_DIR"
    exclude:
```

Below is the output of the plan

```
DEV successfully initialized!
No changes. Your infrastructure matches the configuration.
Terraform has compared your real infrastructure against your configuration
and found no differences, so no changes are needed.
```

Below is my provider file

```
provider "aws" {
  #required_version = ">= 0.13.1"
  region = "us-east-1"
}

terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = ">= 4.9"
    }
  }
  backend "s3" {
    bucket = "terraform-dev-statefile-bucket"
    key    = "statefile-name.tfstate"
    region = "us-east-1"
  }
}
```

when I run `terraform --version` along with init(with backend-config) and validate here is the output

```
Terraform has been successfully initialized!
You may now begin working with Terraform. Try running "terraform plan" to see
any changes that are required for your infrastructure. All Terraform commands
should now work.
If you ever set or change modules or backend configuration for Terraform,
rerun this command to reinitialize your working directory. If you forget, other
commands will detect it and remind you to do so if necessary.
DEV successfully initialized!
variables.tf
╷
│ Warning: Argument is deprecated
│ 
│   with module.s3.aws_s3_bucket.create-s3-bucket,
│   on .terraform/modules/s3/storage/s3/main.tf line 1, in resource "aws_s3_bucket" "create-s3-bucket":
│    1: resource "aws_s3_bucket" "create-s3-bucket" {
│ 
│ Use the aws_s3_bucket_server_side_encryption_configuration resource instead
╵
Success! The configuration is valid, but there were some
validation warnings as shown above.
Terraform v1.7.0
on linux_amd64
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws v5.32.1
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:01
Job succeeded
```

What could be the reason of not persisting the credentials and why does the plan needs the var file to detect the changes?
Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

1º Have you tried to rename the variables? I'd remove the "_PIPELINE_TEST" and "_PIPELINE_SECRET" from the end of names:

- https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/cloud_deployment/#authenticate-gitlab-with-aws
- https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs#environment-variables

2º Maybe you have other paralell infra that not requires the content of var file (debug the tfstate file(s))

Comment: Although I did not have to remove what you suggested but I changed this

        `export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_PIPELINE_TEST}`
        `export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_PIPELINE_SECRET}`
        `export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=${AWS_DEFAULT_REGION}`

That worked for `terraform init` but not for `terraform plan` as it is still not detecting changes if I dont pass the var-file